# Replace only (case insensitive) whole word from string php

Tags: php

```
    $replace = array
        (
            [$name] => John
            [$date] => Aug 17,2020
            [$timezone] => US/Eastern
            [$time] => 23:00
            [$datetime] => Aug 17,2020 23:00
            [$tz] => EDT
            [$dateformat("m/d/y h:i:A")] => 08/17/20 11:00:PM
        )

$message = "This is test Message with $dateformat(\"m/d/y h:i:A\")  & \"Hello\"\n& This test Message again with $tzs";
```

I have above array and string, now I want to replace array keys with array values in given string.

I have tried below code,

```
$final_msg = str_ireplace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $message);
```

Above code gives me below result:

> This is test Message Aug 17,2020format("m/d/y h:i:A")  & "Hello"
> & This test MEssage EDTs $rec

Now issue is that, `$dateformat(\"m/d/y h:i:A\")` should be replace with "08/17/20 11:00:PM", but it does not check for whole world and only $date is replaced Aug 17,2020.

So I want to only whole matched word from message and word can be case insensitive.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Once `$date` got replaced due to your second array entry - how many times do you think, the text `$datetime` or `$dateformat` is still contained in your _current_ text? You will need to _sort_ your input data, so that longer words will be replaced before shorter ones they might potentially overlap with.

Comment: @CBroe By doing sorting it will not help because I need to replace value when whole word match otherwise keep as it is

Comment: _Of course_ sorting helps in this instance, what are you talking about? Check https://3v4l.org/tpld6, if you don’t believe it.

Comment: Sorting by longest `strlen` of keys will help because longest will be sorted first.

Comment: @CBroe, Thanks for solution, In $dateformat this is resolved but if in other case like "$tz", we got value of $tz from array which is EDT. so in message if only $tz word is there then it should replace, but here $tzs also replaced and become EDTs and it should not happen

Comment: Then you will probably have to switch to a regex solution, that can take _word boundaries_ into account. Or switch to a different format of placeholders, that helps avoid such ambiguities.

Answer (score 0):

#1:
You could use the following code, which replace word by word. So I must change m/d/y h:i:A to m/d/y-h:i:A. But it work :D

```
$replace = array (
        '$name' => "John",
        '$date' => "Aug 17,2020",
        '$timezone' => "US/Eastern",
        '$time' => "23:00",
        '$datetime' => "Aug 17,2020 23:00",
        '$tz' => "EDT",
        '$dateformat("m/d/y-h:i:A")' => "08/17/20 11:00:PM"
);

$message = "This is test Message with \$dateformat(\"m/d/y-h:i:A\")  & \"Hello\"\n& This test Message again with \$tz";
$message_array = explode ( " ", $message );
foreach ( $message_array as $key => $element ) {
    foreach ( $replace as $search_str => $replace_str ) {
        if ($element == $search_str)
            $message_array [$key] = $replace_str;
    }
}

$final_msg = implode ( " ", $message_array );
echo $final_msg;
```

#2

```
uksort($replace , function($a, $b) {
   return strlen($a) - strlen($b);
});
```

that will sort  $replace by keylength, avoid you to replace  shorter string before long string.